# Oracle: Converting multiple rows to set number of columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I pretty new to SQL world (2 days) and I basically have the three tables below (content of tables changed but the problem is still the same)

**Names table**

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | CHARACTER |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Bones     |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Booth     |
+----+-----------+
| 3  | Angela    |
+----+-----------+
| 4  | Hodgins   |
+----+-----------+
| 5  | Sweets    |
+----+-----------+
```

**Roles Table**

```
+---------+------------+
| ROLE_ID | ROLE       |
+---------+------------+
| A       | Squint     |
+---------+------------+
| B       | Unemployed |
+---------+------------+
| C       | Cop        |
+---------+------------+
| D       | Young      |
+---------+------------+
| E       | Crazy      |
+---------+------------+
| F       | Smart      |
+---------+------------+
```

**NameAndRole Table**

```
+--------------+----+---------+
| NAME_ROLE_ID | ID | ROLE_ID |
+--------------+----+---------+
| 1            | 1  | A       |
+--------------+----+---------+
| 2            | 1  | C       |
+--------------+----+---------+
| 3            | 1  | E       |
+--------------+----+---------+
| 4            | 1  | F       |
+--------------+----+---------+
| 5            | 2  | C       |
+--------------+----+---------+
| 6            | 3  | A       |
+--------------+----+---------+
| 7            | 4  | A       |
+--------------+----+---------+
| 8            | 4  | E       |
+--------------+----+---------+
```

The result I want is this:

```
+----+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID | CHARACTER | ROLE1  | ROLE2 | ROLE3 |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| 1  | Bones     | Squint | Cop   | Crazy |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| 2  | Booth     | Cop    |       |       |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| 3  | Angela    | Squint |       |       |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| 4  | Hodgins   | Squint | Crazy |       |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| 5  | Sweets    |        |       |       |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Even though a name can technically have more than 3 roles, I just want to print the first 3. Based on countless google searches and Oracle reads, I’m down to understanding that I need to use a LEFT JOIN, nested SELECT and a PIVOT.  I have the statement below but I’m aware that it’s not correct since one, I need the characters in the row and not columns which is what the pivot clause potentically does here and, the statement isn’t running in Oracle with the error:

```
)ON r. ROLE_ID = NameAndRole. ROLE_ID
               *
Error at line 15
ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here
```

The code is:

```
SELECT n.ID,
n.CHARACTER

FROM Names n

LEFT JOIN NameAndRole nr ON n.ID = nr.ID
LEFT JOIN 
(
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Roles r
    )
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(r.role) FOR NameAndRole.NAME_ROLE_ID IN (‘Bones’,’Booth’,’Angela’)
        WHERE NameAndRole.NAME_ROLE_ID<3

    )
)ON r. ROLE_ID = NameAndRole. ROLE_ID

/*I’m not sure as to how much of this is garbage and what’s even usable at this point...*/
```

P.S - This is my first question on Stack anything so if I didn’t follow some well known rules, feel free to let me know.

Comment: It is always helpful to include the full error stack rather than just saying that a statement "isn't running".  Assuming that means that you are getting an error rather than that the query runs but returns a different data set.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I have updated the post with the error I got after fixing a mistake I noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that your query would have worked even if you could fix the error. I'm also not 100% sure how well a `pivot` would have worked here since your desired column names don't match the values.

Still, you can achieve your desired results using conditional aggregation and the `row_number` analytical function. Also, it would be very simple to add more than 3 roles if you ever wanted to.

```
select n.id,
       n.character,
       max(case when r.rn = 1 then r.role end) as role1,
       max(case when r.rn = 2 then r.role end) as role2,
       max(case when r.rn = 3 then r.role end) as role3
  from names n
  left join (select nr.id,
                    r.role,
                    row_number() over (
                      partition by nr.id
                          order by nr.name_role_id) as rn
               from NameAndRole nr
               join roles r
                 on r.role_id = nr.role_id) r
    on r.id = n.id
 group by n.id, n.character
 order by n.id
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but..that worked! Thank you soo much!!